# Finding similarity of strings using distance function : Bounding the distance function?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, mahalanobis-distance

I want to know if 2 binary strings $s$ and $t$ each of $d$ length (dimension) and N = 2 (the alphebet) in this case 0 and 1 are similar to each other or not using the following distance function where $k$ denotes the iteration number or the time index

[image]

Using programming language, I implemented the formula but I am unable to decide if there should be a threshold so that distances less than the threshold are considered similar to each other. The QUestion stems from the tutorial https://www.math.ubc.ca/~andrewr/620341/pdfs/symb_sum.pdf
which mentions another distance function. For both of the distance metric, what is the usual practice of deciding the bound $\epsilon$ in the condition $d(s,t) < \epsilon$

I am having a tough time in understanding the document and not sure if the Authors mean that 2 strings are similar if their distance is less than $1/2^n$ where $n$ is the number of iterations / length of the vector. Shall be greateful for an easier explanation.

How to find the minimum and maximum distance bound? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that document considers strings of infinite length. So the theorem says that if two strings agree on the first $n$ characters, their distance is less than $1/2^n$. If you're dealing with finite strings of length $n$, the smallest distance possible between two distinct strings is $1/2^n$, so in this case if the distance between two strings is less than $1/2^n$, the two strings are the same.

Comment: Thank you for going through the document. The string is of finite length. Will the lower bound $1/2^n$ also apply for the distance function that I have given in the Question?

Comment: If you're only dealing with strings of a finite and fixed length, you should probably use a different distance function. The one that's defined there essentially says that characters that come earlier in the string are more important. In fact, the way it's written, it turns out to just be a scaled version of the difference between two binary integers. That is, you can look at a binary string of length $n$ as an integer between 0 and $2^n-1$. Then the distance between $s$ and $t$ is just $|s-t|/2^{n-1}$.